# Doing a LEFT JOIN with a default value if nothing matches

Tags: mysql

Firstly, I'm not even sure if `LEFT JOIN` is the best way of doing what I want to do, so will try best to explain.

I have 2 tables - one containing a list of sites, and another containing a list of roles. A user may just have one role, but they may have as many roles as there are sites.

**Table 'sites'**

```
site_id  |  site_name  | site_domain
---------------------------------------
1        |  Site A     | sitea.com
2        |  Site B     | siteb.com
```

**Table 'roles'**

```
site_id  |  user_id  | role_id
---------------------------------
1        |  1        | 1
1        |  2        | 1
2        |  2        | 2
```

As in my example above, User 1 has just one role on just one site, but User 2 has two roles on two different sites.

What I'd like to do, and it's probably just a Sunday night not thinking straight kinda thing, is to get a list of sites out, along with the role for each individual user - if no role exists for that site for a user, then return NULL (or 0).

Two examples of how the output should result:

**User 1**

```
site_id | site_name | site_domain | role_id
----------------------------------------------
1       | Site A    | sitea.com   | 1
2       | Site B    | siteb.com   | NULL
```

**User 2**

```
site_id | site_name | site_domain | role_id
----------------------------------------------
1       | Site A    | sitea.com   | 1
2       | Site B    | siteb.com   | 2
```

The query I have at the moment is below, however, the 2nd site does not appear since the user doesn't have a role defined (ie. like above, but for User 1 the 2nd Site B will not list). I know I'm just missing something but cannot think of it tonight :o(

```
SELECT site_id, site_name, site_domain, role_id 
FROM `sites` 
LEFT JOIN `roles` 
ON sites.site_id=roles.site_id 
WHERE roles.user_id='1'
```

Comment: Can you put an example of the result you want?

Comment: The examples show how it should appear, made that a bit clearer above now :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is start with a table that combines all sites and users.  Then join in the information in the `roles` table:

```
select s.site_id, s.site_name, s.site_domain, u.user_id, r.role_id
from (select distinct user_id from roles) u cross join
     sites s left outer join
     roles r
     on s.site_id = r.site_id and
        u.user_id = r.user_id
```

If you have a users table, then you can replace the first subquery with that table.

For the sites where a single user is involved, you can just put a constant in the subquery:

```
select s.site_id, s.site_name, s.site_domain, u.user_id, r.role_id
from (select 1 as user_id) u cross join
     sites s left outer join
     roles r
     on s.site_id = r.site_id and
        u.user_id = r.user_id
```

Or a `where` clause:  `where u.user_id = 1`.

Comment: Thanks - this works perfectly :o) - never done a `CROSS JOIN` before

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` is the same when You join using commas :)

Comment: Just missing the last where u.user_id='1'  xP